# Upper volume bounds for submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:M\to (N,g)$ be an immersion of a compact smooth manifold $M$ into a compact Riemannian manifold $(N,g)$. Let 
$$
\mathrm{Vol}(M,f^*g)=\int_M d\mathrm{vol}_{f^*g}
$$
be the volume of $M$ with respect to the pullback metric $f^*g$.

**My question:** Can we get an upper bound on the volume of $(M,f^*g)$ in terms of curvature properties of the metric $g$?

One possible idea I had: suppose that $(N,g)$ has Ricci curvature bounded below by $\kappa$, i.e. there exists a constant $\kappa\in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
\mathrm{Ric}^N\geq (n-1)\kappa.
$$
Does it follow that $(M,f^*g)$ also has Ricci curvature bounded below by some $\kappa'\in \mathbb{R}$? If so, then we can bound $\mathrm{Vol}(M,f^*g)$ above using the [Bishop-Gromov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality).

Comment: First, there is always a $\kappa'$, as a consequence of compactness.  Second, control of $\kappa'$ is not enough - you can embed $S^1$ into $S^3$ with arbitrarily large length, but $\kappa' = 0$ on $S^1$.   Perhaps control of the second fundamental form is enough?

Comment: You have to restrict to embedding, or you can wrap around itself as many times as you wish.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Do you know what kind of conditions on the ambient metric $g$ could provide a priori bounds on $L^2$ norm of the second fundamental form (or even just the traceless part of the second fundamental form)? I am particularly interested in the case where the submanifold is a surface, so would appreciate any pointers in this direction. Thanks.